# ProgressBar dentro de uma Task

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wpf

Como posso modificar os valores de um controle de interface dentro de uma task separada da thread principal?

### Exemplo:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task task = new Task(Processar);
        task.Start();
    }

public void Processar()
    {
        try
        {
            int i = 0;                

            this.progressBar1.Maximum = 5000000;

            for (i = 0; i < this.progressBar1.Maximum; i++)
            {
                this.progressBar1.Value = i;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Ao executar esse pequeno trecho de código recebo essa msg...

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'progressBar1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

Tentei usar delegate, mas não deu muito certo.

Comment: Usa `Task.Run(() => ...)` em vez de `new Task()` e `task.Start()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando o método [Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) é possível realizar o que você quer:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task task = new Task(Processar);
        task.Start();
    }

    public void Processar()
    {
        try
        {
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => { progressBar1.Maximum = 5000000; }));

            for (int i = 0; i < progressBar1.Maximum; i++)
            {
                Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => { progressBar1.Value = i; }));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }));                
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1, mas julgo que a última linha `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)` também precisa de correr na thread UI.

Comment: Tinha esquecido do MessageBox, editei o código para deixar correto.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente !!! Muito obrigado !!!